# Return condition (in operator) in case statement in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
declare @code varchar(1)
set @code = null

select 
    *
from 
    Employee
where
    Emp_Id in  
    (
    case 
        when @code = null then 1,2,3
        then @code = 1 then 1,3
        when @code = 2 then 2,3
    end
    )
```

I mean if "code = null", the query will be like this:

```
select 
    *
from 
    Employee
where
    Emp_Id in (1,2,3)
```

If "code = 1", the query will be like this:

```
select 
    *
from 
    Employee
where
    Emp_Id in (1,3)
```

I don't want use other operator like OR, need use IN operator.
Any idea ?

Comment: try changing **code = null** with **code is null**, **then code = 1** with **when code = 1** in your second condition for case block and put returned parameters 1,2,3 1,3 and 2,3 in parenthesis ().

Answer (score 2):

You can't return a list type from a `case`, but you can do this:

```
select *
from Employee
where (
    (@code is null and Emp_Id in (1,2,3)) or
    (@code = 1 and Emp_Id in (1,3)) or
    (@code = 2 and Emp_Id in (2,3))
)
```

Note also your attempt included `when @code = null`, which is never true - you must use `is null` when testing for `null` (not `= null`).

Comment: The requirement is use "WHERE IN () ". Do u think its possible ?

Comment: @ThanhPT no, I don't think it's possible

Comment: @ThanhPT - even in above answer `where..In..` is present

Comment: "I don't want use other operator like OR"

Answer (score 0):

Dynamic-sql:

```
declare @code varchar(1)
      , @sql nvarchar(max)

set @code = null

set @sql = N'
select *
  from Employee
  where Emp_Id in  (' + 
    case 
        when @code is null then '1,2,3'
        when @code = 1 then '1,3'
        when @code = 2 then '2,3'
    end +
    ')'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: My query in the question just a example.My real query very long (~50 line), so I can't use this.

Comment: Why you can't use this? I use this for long queries like 500 lines.